# Reactive Framework and INotifyPropertyChanged with Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight-4.0

I am new to the RX framework. Im playing around with it trying to update a Silverlight textbox upon a property updating using INotifyPropertyChanged. My XAML looks like this:

```
 <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Border BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="Blue" Canvas.Left="12" Width="371">
            <TextBlock Height="135" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,50,0,0" Name="textBlock1" 
                       Text=""
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="367" />
        </Border>
        <Button Content="Post!" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,210,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
        <TextBox Height="41" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 Margin="12,247,0,0" 
                 Name="textBox1" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                 Width="376" 
                 />
        <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Content="Post Window" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" Canvas.Left="14" Canvas.Top="0" />
    </Canvas>
```

In my code behind, I have:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        Messanger messanger;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        void messanger_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var textBoxInput = from evt in Observable.FromEvent<PropertyChangedEventArgs>(messanger, "PropertyChanged")
                               select evt.EventArgs.PropertyName.Equals("PropertyName");

            textBoxInput.Subscribe(value => textBlock1.Text = value.ToString());
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            messanger = new Messanger();

            messanger.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(messanger_PropertyChanged);

            messanger.Message = textBox1.Text;
        }

    }
```

and I created another class to handle the property change events

```
 public class Messanger : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string MessageValue;

        public string Message
        {
            get { return MessageValue; }
            set
            {
                MessageValue = value;

                NotifyPropertyChanged("Message");
            }
        }
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }  
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

My problem is that I dont get an output in the Textblock from what I put it in the Textbox. Also let me know if I am using it incorrectly...

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind TextBlock text to TextBox Text like this

```
...
<TextBlock Height="135" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,50,0,0" Name="textBlock1" 
                       Text="{Binding ElementName=textBox1,Path=Text}"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="367" />
...
<TextBox Height="41" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 Margin="12,247,0,0" 
                 Name="textBox1" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                 Width="376" 
                 />
```

Comment: Wouldn't thid defeat the purpose of using the Rx framwork and the Observable?

Comment: I don't think so,you should do correct bindings to for visualizing correct data

Comment: What you are doing is just binding the Textbox to the Textblock. That is fine but not what I want to do. I want the Oberserver to push the data to me (meaning to the Textblock)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in using the reactive framework with Silverlight, you might want to check out [Reactive UI](http://www.reactiveui.net/).